# How to retrieve the email id from facebook users

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to pull the email addresses of all the people who are in my friendlist of facebook.

Is it possible to pull all the email address of my friends using javascript api.

It should be possible to any user, if they provide authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the email addresses of a user's friends.  You can get their basic public information (user_id, display picture etc.).

To get the email address of these users, they would also have to authorise your application.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.I am able to retrieve the email of the user who logs in, what I what to do is suppose I login to the app, I must be able to get all the email id of my friends who are in the facebook friends list. I want to get only email id's. I have added the permission "friendsList"

Comment: I swear that I'm the only one speaking English today.  Please revise your question.

Comment: Please see revised answer.  I've also revised your question so that it is clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ Coulton: yes just realized that. Thank you. Now I need to create a app and if any user clicks on allow they I should be able to get the his/her email address.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the content using by sending a request to the graph api(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) in fb with a valid user access token  ....

1. you can retrieve the user access token via javascript SDK
2. after getting that request the email of that particular user using fb.uimethods

sample code

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
        batch: [
            { method: 'GET', relative_url: 'me'},
            ...
        ]
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

the request url shuld be something like "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=user_acess_token" & this will display the basic details about the user ...